# cant run code on cms page within <a> tag

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml, html

I wanted to link from a cms block within a product page to its corresponding amazon product which can be identified via an custom attribute called "asin".

So I have put the link like

```
<a href="https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/{{block type="core/template" template="amz/asinlinkinject.phtml"}}">...</a>
```

and the idea was, that this injects the asin, stored in the repsective product...

But whats happening; it replaces the

> {{...}}

with somwething like

> "...ms_wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3tibG9jayB0eXBlPSJjb..."

after I exit html mode and go back in wysiwig....

So I guess I am doing something totaly wrong here. How could i get the asin in the link?

> {{block type="core/template" template="amz/asinlinkinject.phtml"}}

which is doing

```
<?php
  echo Mage::registry('current_product')->getasin();
 ?>
```

and it works fine as text outside the  tag .

Answer (score 0):

Move the whole A tag in the template file.

Your CMS block:

```
{{block type="some/customblock" template="amz/asinlinkinject.phtml"}}}
```

Your template `amz/asinlinkinject.phtml`:

```
<a href="https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/<?php echo Mage::registry('current_product')->getAsin(); ?>">...</a>
```

Add `some/customblock` as *Allowed* in **Admin > System > Permissions > Blocks**